# Debian Linux error on logoff because cifs

Tags: linux, debian, cifs

I try to avoid the

> cifs_put_smb_ses: Session Logoff failure rc=-512

error on logoff which came up after about 30 seconds. If I umount the share manually before shutdown, the error does not appear. On log in there are nor errors. Sometimes, if I open the share in Nautilus it takes a while or a timeout came up, but the next try is working.
The user I use has no root privileges.

The share is mounted in /etc/fstab

```
//10.10.10.10/my_share  /media/my_share  cifs credentials=/home/my_username/.smbcredentials,noauto,users,uid=1000,gid=1000,_netdev  0       0
```

I've also tried to mount into /mnt but there mount is working only if I log in with root to the console and do mount -a.